# Redis Cluster nodes not joining after cluster create command

Tags: redis-cluster

Executed a cluster create command to create a 3 master cluster after enabling cluster config in each of the 3 instances, but this cluster create command gets stuck at "Waiting for the cluster to join".

```sh
$ redis-cli --cluster create 127.0.0.1:6379 machine2:6379 machine3:6379 --cluster-replicas 0
```

This cmd was run on machine1.

Getting cluster info as this :

```
cluster_state:fail
cluster_slots_assigned:5462
cluster_slots_ok:5462
cluster_slots_pfail:0
cluster_slots_fail:0
cluster_known_nodes:1
cluster_size:1
cluster_current_epoch:2
cluster_my_epoch:2
cluster_stats_messages_pong_sent:1
cluster_stats_messages_meet_sent:1
cluster_stats_messages_sent:2
cluster_stats_messages_pong_received:1
cluster_stats_messages_meet_received:1
cluster_stats_messages_received:2
```

In my conf file, value of bind = 0.0.0.0

Comment: Can you verify if the redis instance is running on machine2 and machine3?

Comment: Which redis version are you using? Also as far as I know redis-cli for redis version 5.0.3 does not support dns name for servers. In that case you should have mechanism to provide the ip like `dig+` or use direct the ips of the server.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is probably not a good IP if you are accessing multiple machines...